# When would you allow proxy access to your website?

Tags: proxy

A WordPress security course offered a method for blocking visits via a proxy to your website.

In what scenario would this be a bad idea?

i.e. When would you allow proxy access to your website?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Proxies and VPNs are often used by spammers and hackers to hide their true identity.  If you're web site sees a lot of malicious traffic, blocking proxies may be a good idea.  There are several WP plugins that will block proxies and IP addresses with a history of malicious attacks.

Proxies can be used for good and evil.  Many corporate networks uses proxies between browser clients and their intranets and Internet.  It might help you to read https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proxy_server to get a better understanding of how proxies work and to determine if blocking proxies is a good idea or not for your environment.